# Пытаюсь подключиться к БД-ке через консоль, но здесь застрял

Tags: c#, sql, сервер

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь подключиться к БД-ке через консоль(это сервер здесь), но здесь не знаю как делать дальше, застрял
Клиент через серверный часть должен получить таблицу на dataGridView

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // По словам препода: Он должен к клиенту отправлятся
 da.Fill(ds, "Employees");

В клиенте куда его поставить?
Клиент на WinForms'е
[image: Вот код, но не полностью]

Comment: dataGridView  есть? Найдите его Init. И весь этот код не в Main должен быть. Скорее в Init формы.

Comment: извините, можете простым языком объяснить?

Comment: dataGridview есть на клиенте, а init где находиться?

Comment: Это событие формы.

Comment: Клиент должен получать от сервера данные в каком формате?

Comment: он на datagridview получить список людей

Comment: Просто нельзя классы посылать. Их надо сначала сериализовать, а потом у клиента десериализовать.

Comment: По сути так: Бд->Сервер->Клиент

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
вот тут сверху Dataset

Comment: спасибо, сейчас прочиаю